# OK to disable TLS1.0 with IIS and SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2, tls, sql-server-2014

([This identical question in dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126815/how-can-we-have-iis-talk-to-sql-server-with-tls1-0-disabled) is drawing a blank)

**Background**

We need PCI-DSS compliance, and so must disable TLS1.0. In my test environment we have SQL Server 2014 SP1 with CU 1 (as per [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107820/sql-server-compatibility-with-new-tls-standards)) and IIS 8 all on the same box. I used the [Nartac IIS Crypto tool](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1073492/sql-server-depends-on-old-ssl-tls-versions) to disable TLS1.0 and rebooted. That's when my troubles began.

SQL Agent won't start, SSMS can't connect to the server, and the website stops working. (Fortunately, I *can* still make a Remote Desktop Connection to my test server.)

Then I read [Microsoft's article](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1073492/sql-server-depends-on-old-ssl-tls-versions) which says basically SQL Server just has to have TLS1.0.

**Question**

Can I fix this? (Maybe I need a separate box in the test environment for SQL Server?)

**Edit**

I've changed my test environment so that IIS and SQL Server are on different boxes.  TLS1.0 is disabled on the IIS box.  I've modified the registry settings to enable outgoing calls (i.e. to the SQL box) over TLS1.0 while denying incoming calls (i.e. from website users) using John Louros' powershell script (sorry, insufficient reputation to post the link). Still no luck.

Comment: John Louros' script: http://johnlouros.com/blog/disabling-cryptographic-protocols-for-pci-compliance

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out eventually.  The steps are [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126815/how-can-we-have-iis-talk-to-sql-server-with-tls1-0-disabled/127065#127065).  Essentially: separate boxes for IIS and SQL, then only disable TLS1.0 coming *into* the IIS box.